# RAII when using ascyc c library

Tags: c++, raii, nats.io

I have an RAII wrapper around the `cnats` library.  We don't need to understand the details of `cnats`.  There are just two important piecies.  `cnats` is the C client for communicating with a NATS message broker.  As is usually the case, they have custom creation and deletion functions for all of their structures.

I have an RAII wrapper for creating a `natsMsg` object.  The constructor:

```
NatsMessage(const std::string& subject, const std::string& data) {
        natsMsg* temp;
        HANDLE_STATUS(natsMsg_Create(&temp, subject.c_str(), nullptr, data.c_str(), data.size()));
        msg = std::shared_ptr<natsMsg>(temp, [](natsMsg* p) {natsMsg_Destroy(p);});
    }
```

There are two publish functions: `js_PublishMsg` and `js_PublishMsgAsync`.  The regular function just publishes the message.  I am presently adding support for the Async version which takes over the message and calls the `natsMsg_Destroy` when it is done causing a race condition and a double free error.

From reading about `std::shared_ptr`:

> The ownership of an object can only be shared with another shared_ptr by copy constructing or copy assigning its value to another shared_ptr.

There is similar language for `std::unique_ptr`.

In essence my problem is that I would like to use a smart_pointer with a custom deleter.  When I call the Async publish function, I would like to somehow "remove" ownership so that the c library handles the deletion.

I'm okay switching to a `unique_ptr` or other smart pointer (or some other way of accomplishing this).

Comment: `unique_ptr` has a release function. you can also set a flag in the deleter.

Comment: Although imo there is no much reason to use smart pointer here anyway. The destructor can simply handle it.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  It you change it to an answer I'll accept it.  I didn't use the constructor/destructor to manage it because I was thinking of a shared ownership model.  It would probably be fine as long as I delete the copy constructor/assignment operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't need shared ownership, you can use `std::unique_ptr` which has [`release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) function

```cpp
struct NatsMessage{
    NatsMessage() {
        natsMsg* temp;
        GetMsg(&temp);
        msg.reset(temp);

        // when you need to transfer ownership to C library
        // natsMsg* m = msg.release();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<natsMsg,decltype(&natsMsg_Destroy)> msg = {nullptr, &natsMsg_Destroy};
};
```

---

- if you want to keep using `std::shared_ptr`, you can set some flag to disable the deleter.
- also you can use raw pointer and manually release it in destructor, note this also require correctly handle copy/move case.